# C#, using a regular expression to find and replace certain characters in a word?

Tags: c#, regex

I need something that will find a word enclosed in two "%" signs, and replace the first `%` with a `[` and the second `%` sign with a `]`.

So in the string "This is dummy text %with% percent signs"
It will then make it "This is dummy text [with] percent signs"

EDIT: Would there be a way to search and replace two different things in the same regex? Like I need to replace %blah% with [blah] but also %~dp1 with [~dp1] the %~dp1 call is in the format %~(could be some letters here)(always ends with a single digit thats how you know the call is over) sorry this is the last thing :)

Comment: what should be the output of this string '% % %' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would match the whole substring enclosed by the special characters, and replace it with a string containing the same inner characters but with brackets instead of percent signs. Make sure you use nongreedy matching if the input can have many of these substrings:

```
Regex.Replace("This is dummy text %with% percent signs", "%(.*?)%", @"[$1]");
```

Comment: Since OP specified a "word" between two % he might also replace .*? with \S+ (one or more non-whitespace chars) ie "%(\S+)%"

Comment: That code won't compile, as `\[` is not a recognized escape sequence in c# string.

Comment: @svick - You are correct; I added the @ changing it to a verbatim string, which should properly escape it. \[ is still valid in regex; it denotes a literal opening square bracket, instead of a character-grouping construct.

Comment: @KeithS, yeah, this will compile, but will produce strings with literal `\[` (and `\]`) in them.

Comment: In the *replacement* string, `[` and `]` have no special meaning, so they don't need to be escaped.  `"[$1]"` (or `@"[$1]"`) will work just fine.

Comment: Would there be a way to search and replace two different things in the same regex?
Like I need to replace %blah% with [blah]
but also %~dp1 with [~dp1]
the %~dp1 call is in the format %~(could be some letters here)(always ends with a single digit thats how you know the call is over)
sorry this is the last thing :)

Comment: @Joey: Yes; the pattern to match would be `@"%(~[A-Za-z]+\d)"` with the same replacement string as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "%([^%]+)%", "[$1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MatchEvaluator to provide the replacement value.  Alternate with `(i++ % 2)`

```
int i = 0;
Regex.Replace(s, "%", m => (i++ % 2) == 0 ? "[" : "]");
```